# Link stories in an Azure Board Sprint to a release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm using the Agile Process template in Azure Boards to run Scrum.  I need to be able to link a story to a release so that I can report on what features shipped in a given release.

In Jira, I would have done it by creating a Release, and then adding completed stories to the release as they finished, and then finally "releasing" the release once we shipped to prod (usually a few days after the sprint ends, since our sprint ends on Friday/we don't release on the weekend)

I don't see a similar mechanism in Azure boards.  I have iterations, but even if I assume an iteration == a release, that doesn't account for hotfixes or for stories that don't finish during a sprint.

Any advice on how to handle these?

Answer (score 0):

We manage this with a Release Iteration. In that iteration/sprint, we have our regression activities, then our non-functionals like documentation updates. Under that documentation story is a release note task, where we use a query to pull the release note text from items under the parent iteration. e.g. `product\version\sprint 1`, `product\version\sprint 2`, `product\version\release sprint`, and we query release note text `where iteration path under product\version`.

Stories we don't finish are de-scoped so the iteration path is set back to the backlog. If we deliver some of the functionality, we just move out the tasks/bugs which we want to backlog to come back to.